# Php redirect to url without www if possible

Tags: php, session, redirect, proxy

I have small proxy when i need to get same **URLS** from same website, but in some websites **URL** could be with `WWW` and without, i was going to cut `WWW` and redirect to `http://` only. 
But some sites redirect to `http://www` anyway and im getting **infinite redirect**.

Thats why i have tried to redirect without `WWW` and if it still with `WWW` *(after redirect)* leave it with `http://www`.

I was trying to avoid this by `$_SESSION` where i can store if it was redirected or not, and execute redirect if not.

But it still infinite redirecting me on website with `www` im searching the solution several days. - and still nothing. Passing if redirected in `$_GET` paramenter is not exit, because **url** should be clean.

Also im storing domain in `session` to know that user change website and need to check for `www`.

```
if(session_id() == '') {
    session_start();
}
if(strpos($_url, "www")!==false) {
    if(!isset($_SESSION['redirected'])) {
        $_SESSION['redirected']=get_domain($_url);
        $url = preg_replace('#^(http(s)?://)?w{3}\.(\w+\.\w+)#', '$1$3', $url);
        header("Location: ".$script_url . '?' . $config.'='.$url);      
        exit(0);
    }
    elseif($_SESSION['redirected']!=get_domain($_url)) {
        $url = preg_replace('#^(http(s)?://)?w{3}\.(\w+\.\w+)#', '$1$3', $url);
        header("Location: ".$script_url . '?' . $config.'='.$url);      
        exit(0);
    }
}
session_destroy();
```

Comment: *I have small proxy when i need to get same URLS from same website* - what does that mean? You are building a proxy? Youz act as a proxy? You are behind a proxy? Your situation is very unclear.

Comment: I have download PHPproxy-master from github, and tring to improve it

Comment: Well that was worth mentioning wasn't it? :D  I still fail to see what you are doing here. You want to strip www from every call, doing so by redirecting the user. But then you end up on www again somehow?

Comment: something like that https://github.com/emersion/phproxy

Comment: Yeah sorry :D .I want to redirect without www if it possible (i mean if server dont redirect to http://www)

Comment: That still doesn't provide the information needed to help you.
What is your desired output? What is your scenario? What is your environment? What is your input?

Comment: So your software runs on serveral servers and some redirect to www automatically while you redirect to *without www*. So your Problem is the http Settings of the servers your software is running on right? You could have a htaccess File in your project that overwrites such htaccess rules. Your Session Solution can't work since the session is bound to the domain and thus will not be available after the redirect :-/

Comment: Thanks that trying to help me, im very glad. The scenario is 1) get url from `$_GET` 2) redirect from `www` to `http://` if possible 3) `fsockopen` and walk over content to rebuild `href`s and so on 4) attach some elements to page 5) echo result.  - I have found why its loops infinite - the problem is that im redirecting and check `url` and only after im trying to `fsockopen` when i can redirected too - thats why im getting infinite redirect. I will try to make new question how to get final `url` from `fsockopen`