# Get final URL from fsockopen

Tags: php, curl, proxy

I need to get final `URL` after `fsockopen` i means final because host could redirect me - and i need to get `URL` which is makes on the final stage. Why i need it you can look here [Php redirect to url without www if possible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23494216/php-redirect-to-url-without-www-if-possible)

I was trying to find same questions but some of them are using `CURL` but some servers don`t support it, and i need to rebuild all script for it.

ps Sorry if duplicate

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`fsockopen` doesn't do redirects. You are confused with `fopen` that does follow redirects in its quest to fetch the resource, when used with the [http-wrapper](https://www.php.net/manual/en/wrappers.http.php), and gives you a (read-only) handler to the body of the resource. When used with the [http-wrapper](https://www.php.net/manual/en/wrappers.http.php), the headers encountered on the way are stored in the variable `$http_response_header`, which can be processed to see the final URL.

`fsockopen` however just opens a stream to a socket, and therefore does not follow redirects. `fsockopen` isn't even HTTP aware. It just opens a TCP socket for reading from and writing to.

Comment: Oh really, thats why it returns `resource`. But how can i get the final url from `fopen` after all server redirects?

Comment: @MaximAleksandrovich I just edited my answer for that